# Bulk invite people to an Azure static web app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication, azure-static-web-app

I've spend quite a lot of time trying to find the best way to add authentication to our Azure static web app. Eventually we settled for the easiest solution. restricting all routes for the app and doing our authentication using role management in Azure.

So far we've invited a few users, but we want to invite multiple users to our web app at once. Possibly add each user to some sort of group and inviting the whole group at once?  I couldn't find anything on the 'Role management' page. We have limited knowledge of Azure so far.

I was hoping, could anyone give me a lead on how these things usually work in Azure? I'm struggling at the moment to find the right documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the references below:

1. You can only add 25 invitees/users(individual) to have custom roles via invitation but unlimited users can be assigned roles with a serverless function. This allows you flexibility in how you want to manage roles and you're not restricted in the number of users who can have custom roles.
2. Bulk invitation is not yet possible for role management in azure static web app and is in recent feature request .You can check here

**References:**

1. [Assign Azure Static Web Apps roles with Microsoft Graph | Microsoft
   Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/assign-roles-microsoft-graph)
2. [Authentication and authorization for Azure Static Web Apps |
   Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization?tabs=function#role-management)

> **Note**:Bulk invitation is possible in azure active directory where we
> can fill in csv template and submit: [Azure AD | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/tutorial-bulk-invite#:%7E:text=%20Invite%20guest%20users%20in%20bulk%20%201,an%20invitation%207%20Save%20the%20file.%20See%20More.)

You can raise a support request for the same from overview page> under Support + troubleshooting>new support request